# MVC 3. Drop Down box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am new to MVC 3 just a beginner. I am trying to create a new drop down box in the view but I am getting the error saying "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments".

Here is the View Code

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>
        Customer Name
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(A => A.Roles, Model.Roles);
    </td>
</tr>
```

Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Model = new Customer();
            Model.Roles = getRoles();

            return View(Model);
        }

        private List<string> getRoles()
        {
            List<string> roles = new List<string> 
            {
                "Developer",
                "Tester",
                "Project Manager",
                "Team Lead",
                "QA"
            };
            return roles;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firdt I'd recommend that you create a viewmodel class for your view:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }

    public string SelectedRole { get; set; }
}
```

Then call the view like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<string> roles = new List<string> 
    {
        "Developer",
        "Tester",
        "Project Manager",
        "Team Lead",
        "QA"
    };

    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

    viewModel.Roles = roles;

    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

Then finally, render the dropdown list:

```
@model Mvc4.Controllers.IndexViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRole, new SelectList(Model.Roles))
```

You needed a variable for storing the selected item (`SelectedRole`) and you need to wrap the selection of roles into a `SelectList`, since the dropdown helper cannot use an `IEnumerable` for the second parameter.